# How I can enable Wildcard index at the time of collection creation using Azure CLI command in Cosmosdb Mongo API?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, azure-cli, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

az cosmosdb mongodb collection create -g  -a  -d  -n  --idx @indexes.json

Running command in this format is giving error:
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: ..... Index definition does not contains '_id' index specification.

My indexes.json file content is as shown underneath:

```
[
   { "_id": 1 },
   {
     "key": 
        {"keys":["$**"]},
           "options":{"Wildcard":true}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this json instead.

```
"indexes": [
    {
        "key": {
            "keys": [
                "_id"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key": {
            "keys": [
                "$**"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: yes, that worked for me. It created "_id" as 'Single field' index and "$**" as 'Wildcard' index.  Kudos to you.

Comment: Great. Can you mark the question as answered so others can benefit? Thanks.